# Laravel work with pivot table with 3 or more columns

Tags: mysql, laravel, pivot, many-to-many

I'm trying to insert data in a table that has a MANY TO MANY relationship, part of this data must go to a bridge table (customer_works) where there are 4 columns.

the structure of the bridge table is as follows:

```
id | customer_id | work_id | user_id
--------------------------------------
1 |       3      |    6    |    10
2 |       1      |    9    |    8
```

this is my public function in controller file:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();


        $validatedData = $request->validate([

            'work_type'=>'required',
            'dead_line'=>'required',
            'finished'=>'required',
            'information'=>'required',

        ]);

        $newWork = new Work;
        $newWork->fill($validatedData);
        $newWork->save();

        $newWork->users()->attach('user_id');
        $newWork->customers()->attach('customer_id');
    }
```

it doesn't work...

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: is the new work being saved?^

Comment: yes, the new work is saved @AlbertoSinigaglia